# Marklogic backup status

Tags: marklogic

I would like to know XQuery to display only specific information ( Foresetname & status as below ) instead of all  other information from the backup status command xquery version "1.0-ml"; xdmp:database-backup-status((), xdmp:hosts())

Please can you help me provide me the Xquery command to get the desired output with just Forestname and status .

DCPP_pe_Forest1
in-progress

Answer (score 2):

Please take a look at the documentation example [on this page](http://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp:database-backup-status). You can see the returned data structure by the [`xdmp:database-backup-status()`](http://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp:database-backup-status) function. Based on that you can use standard XPath to retrieve the information that you're after by extracting the `job:status` and `job:forest-name` elements.

Comment: declare namespace database = "http://marklogic.com/xdmp/database";
declare namespace forest = "http://marklogic.com/xdmp/status/forest";
let $cfg := admin:get-configuration()
let $dbnames := "XXXXXX"
for $db in $dbnames
(: get forests :)
for $forestid in admin:database-get-attached-forests($cfg, xdmp:database($db))
let $forest_status := xdmp:forest-status($forestid)
return fn:concat ( $db ,"::", $forest_status/forest:forest-name, "::", $forest_status/forest:forest-id,"::",$forest_status/forest:state,"::", $forest_status/forest:last-backup,"::", $forest_status/forest:backups)

Comment: Error
query evaluated in DCPP_p2 at DCPP_p2_Modules:/ as 1.0-ml
[1.0-ml] XDMP-NONMIXEDCOMPLEXCONT: fn:data(<backups xmlns="http://marklogic.com/xdmp/status/forest"><backup>...</backup></backups>) -- Node has complex type with non-mixed complex content
Stack Trace
At line 15 column 0:
In xdmp:eval("xquery version &quot;1.0-ml&quot;;&#10;&#10;import module namesp...", (), <options xmlns="xdmp:eval"><database>3724338050313901201</database>...</options>)

Comment: Above Xquery throws error while adding the element $forest_status/forest:backups . Please advise

Comment: Again, I can only refer you to the documentation. Under http://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp:forest-status we state that 'backups' is a complex element that has following element children. You need to extract those: `return fn:concat ($db ,"::", $forest_status/forest:forest-name, "::", $forest_status/forest:forest-id, "::", $forest_status/forest:state, "::", $forest_status/forest:last-backup,"::", $forest_status/forest:backups/forest:backup)`